# Как сделать переход по внешним ссылкам используя переход по якорям?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В чём суть, есть скрипт перехода по якорям он берёт во внимание все ссылки из заданой области например меню, как сделать так чтобы работали якорные ссылки и переходило на внешние, так как при нажатию ничего не происходит

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu").on("click", "a", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('href'),
      top = $(id).offset().top;

    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: top
    }, 1500);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#menu").on("click","a", function (event) {
    var id  = $(this).attr('href');
    if ($(id).length) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: $(id).offset().top}, 1500);
    }
  });
});
```